# using python with Sendgrid on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, sendgrid

I am trying to use Sendgrid to send the email on Heroku, but I get the output that I not seen before. I saw the documentation and it says that the helper library supports few versions of python until 3.8 but mine version is 3.9. Is it this cause me get this error?

**Here is my code: **

```
import os
from sendgrid import SendGridAPIClient
from sendgrid.helpers.mail import Mail

message = Mail(
    from_email='hesheitaliabu@gmail.com',
    to_emails='hesheitaliabu@gmail.com',
    subject='Sending with Twilio SendGrid is Fun',
    html_content='<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with Python</strong>')
try:
    sg = SendGridAPIClient('SG.API_KEY')
    response = sg.send(message)
    # print(response.status_code)
    print(response.body)
    print(response.headers)
except Exception as e:
    print(e.message)
```

**I get an error:**

```
b''
Server: nginx
Date: Mon, 05 Sep 2022 03:53:19 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
X-Message-Id: Y19VjElqRe2byQxJrkJUeg
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://sendgrid.api-docs.io
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Content-Type, On-behalf-of, x-sg-elas-acl
Access-Control-Max-Age: 600
X-No-CORS-Reason: https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Basics/API/cors.html
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=600; includeSubDomains
```

Comment: Can you run the same command but using the `--log=DEBUG` flag and show me the output?

Comment: Also, it looks like you included your SendGrid API key in your question. I've edited it out, but it's still visible in the history of the question. I recommend you delete your SendGrid API key and create another one to use.

Comment: @philnash I don't know what is --log=DEBUG sorry. Are you mean debug the .py file? After I debug, I get this:
b''
Server: nginx
Date: Mon, 05 Sep 2022 04:46:56 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
X-Message-Id: VNzmVFUYS-ud1xhK4Z0mFw
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://sendgrid.api-docs.io
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Content-Type, On-behalf-of, x-sg-elas-acl
Access-Control-Max-Age: 600
X-No-CORS-Reason: https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Basics/API/cors.html
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=600; includeSubDomains

Comment: How are you actually running this code? That debugging you are showing there seems to just be the response headers from the API request and they aren't telling me a lot about what's going on. Indeed, in your code you actually call `print(response.headers)` and I think that might be what you are seeing. The API may in fact be returning a successful result.

Comment: I use the Visual Studio Code to run this .py file. But the fact is I really get the same result and the error is same as mentioned above.

Comment: So, two things. If you're running in VS Code then it's not on Heroku. And like I said, you are seeing the headers being printed out, which is the success part of the code. So I think the code is working as expected. Do you receive the email?

Comment: I am going to test and run in the .py file first. If the code doesn't have error, then i only will put in Heroku. I didn't receive any email

Comment: Sure, it's just the Heroku part is irrelevant if you are still testing on your machine. Have you [verified the email address you are sending from as a single sender](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/sending-email/sender-verification)?

Comment: I found that I have successfully sent the email before. But is in the spam instead of inbox there. How do I send email to inbox?

Answer (score 0):

As we've worked out in the comments, the emails are in fact sending successfully. The message you see logged are the response headers from the API because of these lines:

```py
    sg = SendGridAPIClient('SG.API_KEY')
    response = sg.send(message)
    print(response.body)
    print(response.headers)
```

In this case the message is sent and then the program prints out the response body (which is empty for a successfully sent message) and then the response headers, which you are seeing. This is not an error.

Instead, we have worked out that your email is being sent to the spam inbox.

This is a bit harder to fix as it relies on email inbox providers. However I need to point out one thing that's going to make this very difficult to start with.

Your example shows that you are sending the email from your Gmail address to the same Gmail address. Because of this, Gmail knows it did not send the email from that Gmail address and will instantly treat it as suspicious. You are effectively spoofing your own email address. If you have set up [single sender verification with SendGrid](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/sending-email/sender-verification) for that address, all that does is tell SendGrid that you own the email address and aren't trying to spoof just anyone's email address. This is good for testing that you can use the API to send emails.

However, if you want emails to arrive in inboxes and not the spam inbox then your best bet is to send from a domain that you own that you can [authenticate with SendGrid](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/account-and-settings/how-to-set-up-domain-authentication). When you authenticate a domain it sets a number of things like SPF and DKIM that show the inboxes you are sending to that you are the rightful owner of the domain and are authenticated to send emails from the domain. This means you are more likely to arrive in the inbox and not spam.

There is much more to pay attention to to ensure your emails stay out of spam, but in this case, I would start with domain authentication.